# why do not occur side effect before rendering in react(function component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

why do not occur side effects before rendering in react?

I think there are two reasons:

1. side effects occur every rendering

```
function Component(){
  // do something side effects

  return <h1>Hello, World</h1>
}
```

in the above code, side effects occur every rendering, but with useEffect, we can decide whether to skip, and we can cleanUp some side effects

2. side effects can also block rendering

```
function Component(){
  // do something side effects that takes 10 seconds

  return <h1>Hello, World</h1>
}
```

in the above code, rendering is blocked for 10 seconds

```
function Component(){
  useEffect(()=>{
   // do something side effects that takes 10 seconds
  })
  

  return <h1>Hello, World</h1>
}
```

but in this code, rendering is non-block for 10 seconds, because we use the useEffect hook(after the render, that side effect may occur)

---

I used to think like this, but I have a question.

Since JavaScript can operate asynchronously, if side effects are asynchronous, it will not block rendering. If so, the second reason may not be valid, but I wonder if there is another opinion on this.

And I wonder if there are any other reasons why side effects should not occur before render

Answer (score 1):

Side effects is not something that takes a lot of time. A side effect in a function, is something that can be observed outside the function (not including the return value). When a react component `logs to the console, makes an API call, creates an object in storage etc.`, it is performing a side effect.

You are correct if you write something like:

```
function Component(){
  // make async call

  return <h1>Hello, World</h1>
}
```

The return will execute without waiting for the async call to complete. But if it is in the main body of the function then it is called every time. Do you really want that?

A side effect can be performed in the useEffect, or in event handlers. The main idea is to not call them directly from the React function. A react function should have only two tasks - render the output, and handling events. Anything other than these main effects is a side effect.

**Note:** You can call side effects from anywhere you want but you will be deviating from functional programming and pure functions, which is the base of React.